# ejabberdctl debug console terminating

Tags: ejabberd, erlang

We've four eJabberd nodes in cluster node name xmpp[1-4]
Among the four nodes, `ejabberdctl debug` command is not giving the console in two of the nodes (`xmpp1` and `xmpp4`) instead the process is terminating.

- ejabberd version:22:05
- erlang/OTP release: 25
- Os: Ubuntu 18.04 LTS
- Installation : from source.

```
ejabberd@xmpp4:~$ ejabberdctl status 
The node 'ejabberd@xmpp4.gims' is started with status: started
ejabberd 22.05 is running in that node
ejabberd@xmpp4:~$ ejabberdctl list_cluster 
'ejabberd@xmpp4.gims'
'ejabberd@xmpp2.gims'
'ejabberd@xmpp3.gims'
'ejabberd@xmpp1.gims'
ejabberd@xmpp4:~$ ejabberdctl debug
--------------------------------------------------------------------

IMPORTANT: we will attempt to attach an INTERACTIVE shell
to an already running ejabberd node.
If an ERROR is printed, it means the connection was not successful.
You can interact with the ejabberd node if you know how to use it.
Please be extremely cautious with your actions,
and exit immediately if you are not completely sure.

To detach this shell from ejabberd, press:
  control+c, control+c

--------------------------------------------------------------------
To bypass permanently this warning, add to ejabberdctl.cfg the line:
  EJABBERD_BYPASS_WARNINGS=true
Press return to continue


Erlang/OTP 25 [erts-13.1.4] [source] [64-bit] [smp:16:16] [ds:16:16:10] [async-threads:1] [jit:ns]

*** ERROR: Shell process terminated! (^G to start new job) ***

BREAK: (a)bort (A)bort with dump (c)ontinue (p)roc info (i)nfo
       (l)oaded (v)ersion (k)ill (D)b-tables (d)istribution
^C
ejabberd@xmpp4:~$
```

Can somebody please provide help/tips to find the reason for the termination? I was able to get the debug console in other two instances (`xmpp2` and `xmpp3`). There is no resource restriction on the servers as enough RAM is available and number of open files has set to a much higher value.

Comment: Did you check the log files?

Comment: Yes, but I couldn't  find  any(log level : info) . The ejabberd installation is upgraded from the previous versions 21.12

Comment: Increasing the log level could be helpful.